# extract wallet address from private key

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I am using bitcoin core library in node js.

```
const privateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey('testnet');
const address = privateKey.toAddress('testnet);
```

When i `console.log` it, it get result as below. How can i extract the address part only? I try to use `address.Address` but it returns undefined

```
<Address: mmNeqV9HWKUDRUAVdknRKDPHyKYGpBEDzm, type: pubkeyhash, network: testnet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to get public key first then convert it to address

```
var publicKey = privateKey.toPublicKey();
var address = publicKey.toAddress(Networks.livenet);
```

`address` is an object, you can use it as a string. if you want to see it in console try

```
console.log("Address: ", address);
```

Comment: why is it better to get public key first before convert it to address? I found that it returns the same result also even without convert to public key first. any  technical explanation on that?

Comment: Because you're creating the address from the public key not from the private key. so technically for better understanding when you call `privateKey.toAddress` bitcore by default get the `publicKey` and then the address.

Comment: please see this answer here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75910/how-to-generate-a-native-segwit-address-and-p2sh-segwit-address-from-a-standard

Answer (score 1):

You should have the public key first to get bitcoin address.

```
var publicKey = privateKey.toPublicKey();
var address = publicKey.toAddress(Networks.livenet);
```

Check out the [link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address) to know "How bitcoin address is generated from the public key".

Better to try yourself in this [Playground](http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address).

Answer (score 0):

Highly confusing.
Just console log it **AS A STRING**.

This line

```
console.log("address", "" + address);
```

will print out

```
address 1HSfafDJ6ijRxSjj2aTAq2Vb63TAnQK9fz
```

On the other hand if you just log the address object

```
console.log("address", address);
```

You will get

```
address Address {
  hashBuffer: <Buffer b4 5c 9d e7 ce 0c 89 ee aa 5e 8a 24 b2 5a ff 0b dd f6 9d 42>,
  network: Network {
    name: 'livenet',
    alias: 'mainnet',
    pubkeyhash: 0,
    privatekey: 128,
    scripthash: 5,
    bech32prefix: 'bc',
    xpubkey: 76067358,
    xprivkey: 76066276,
    networkMagic: <Buffer f9 be b4 d9>,
    port: 8333,
    dnsSeeds: [
      'seed.bitcoin.sipa.be',
      'dnsseed.bluematt.me',
      'dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org',
      'seed.bitcoinstats.com',
      'seed.bitnodes.io',
      'bitseed.xf2.org'
    ]
  },
  type: 'pubkeyhash'
}
```